# ImageIcon: How to change ImageIcon When click on button

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I want to set image on `#JLabel`. Image get from data base with full address. but i can't change.
and Use ImageIcon class.

Comment: why? why you can' change?

Comment: please add a fragment of your code. Without that we can't localise your problem